# Get belongs_to association in FactoryGirl to work right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, factory-bot

I'm trying to get associations in FactoryGirl to work, and they just ... don't.  I've basically got this:

```
class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :bar
end

class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :foos
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo, class => Foo do
    bar
  end

  factory :bar, class => Bar do
  end
end
```

At least so the docs lead me to believe...  But then in my test, I have

```
a_foo=FactoryGirl.create :foo
a_foo.bar # Hooray! It's an associated object
Foo.where( _id: a_foo._id ).includes( :bar ).first.bar # This is nil!
```

Why is the associated value nil on the last line?  I need it not to be, because the actual code being tested does this same thing, and it has a right to expect it to work...  What am I missing about why this doesn't work right?  Something to do with eager loading, perhaps?

Comment: there is no `has_one` statement?

Comment: I don't often use MongoDB with Rails, but I'm assuming that Foo.find(id) still works, yes? If so, what happens when you try `Foo.find(a_foo._id).bar`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post to indicate that the real code has a `has_many` relationship.  @Samo, it's nil, just like in the line of code in my question...

Comment: Has your bar been saved to the database? Maybe you're creating an invalid bar so it won't let you save?

Comment: I've verified that the bar is, in fact, in the database, fwiw.

Comment: Which version of Mongoid and MongoDB are you using? I [copied your script](https://gist.github.com/pascalj/06066fa01160a8b38fd3) and it works perfectly. Edit: using MongoDB 2.2.0 and Mongoid 3.1.2.

Comment: Mongoid 3.0.14 and MongoDB 2.0.6...  if it works for you then I guess something idiosyncratic and weird is going on that SO can't really help with - sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works for me with FactoryGirl 4.2.0, Mongoid 3.0.9.  But I've run into similar issues when I've been running mongoid with the identitymap disabled (which is default behavior).  Without the identitymap, you can have two different ruby objects representing the same document in the database, getting out of sync with each other.  So, if you have `autosave` off, for example, this could cause the problem you're seeing.

Try pasting your simplified code into the rails console yourself -- if it works, then you probably changed something significant in pairing down your real code.  (Sorry to point out the obvious, but the fact that you have a syntax error in your factory code makes me think you didn't actually test your sample code.)